# I can't get https working with symfony 2

Tags: symfony, ssl

Hi I want to use ssl pages for a symfony 2 website.  I've added

```
    schemes:  [https]
```

to app/config/routing.yml

I also tried adding it to the routing.yml in the bundle itself.

Is does not resolve to a https://www.mysite.com address

Am I missing anything or need to do something else?  Thanks

Further testing I've changed the security.yml to

```
      security:
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory: ~

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    default:
        anonymous: ~
        #anonymous: ~
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

access_control:
 #   - { path: ^/admin/secured/hello/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
   - { path: ^/signup,  requires_channel: https }
```

this works locally on Ubuntu and apache, it redirects to https.  However on my live server Centos, apache with plesk installed it does nothing just stays as http.  Must be some configuration on the server

Comment: Did you set-up SSL in your webserver?

Comment: Yes of course, it works if I go to https://www.mysite.com but to get the routing for the signup and login pages in https:// is what I want

Comment: What error message is shown?

Comment: No error I just don't have a secure padlock showing in url

Answer (score 0):

I never found a way for it to work via the security.yml file and changing the .htaccess won't as you need to use that to route the web/app.php of symfony. The solution I've found is the following with my particular server being administered with plesk it involved some extra steps.

```
  Create a file called vhost.conf in /www/vhosts/system/yousite.com/conf/
```

Add these lines

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*)  https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Save file

Also you need to make sure the permissions are correct, by running the following commands in SSH:

```
chown -R apache /var/www/vhosts/system/yoursite.com/conf
chmod -R 644 /var/www/vhosts/system/yoursite.com/conf
```

Then run:

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/websrvmng --reconfigure-vhost --vhost-name=yoursite.com
```

To apply the changes and have the vhost.conf read by the httpd.conf file.